# Pull back of a Bounded form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, pullback

Let $(X, \omega) $ be a complex manifold and let $\alpha $ be a $p$-form $\omega$-bounded on $X$.
Let $f:Y\to X$ be a holomorphic function.

Is $f^*\alpha$ $f^*(\omega)$-bounded on $Y$ ?

Comment: Definition of $\omega$--bounded? Is $\omega$ a metric?

Comment: Yes $\omega$ is a metric it is a (1,1)form positive definite.

Comment: Bounded with respect to $\omega $

Comment: It depends. For example, if $\alpha = 0$, then the answer is always yes. Probably, you mean: Is $f^*\alpha$ bounded with respect to $f^*\omega$ for all $p$-forms $\alpha$ that are bounded with respect to $\omega$. In that case, I suggest you write out everything in local coordinates. The answer is straightforward.

Comment: #Deane Can you explain me, how can answer clearly this question, thank you in advance

Comment: Could you first rewrite the question more carefully? If what I suggested above is in fact what you mean, then I suggest rewriting the question accordingly.

Comment: What you saggested above is correct, Is $f^*(\alpha) $ bounded with respect to the pseudo-metric $f^*(\omega) $ for all $p-$forms $\alpha $that are bounded with respect to $\omega $?